# specific table layout

Tags: tables, tabularx

I want to draw a table like this: 
[image: table]

with the table width being a portion of the line width, like e.g. 0.8 * linewidth.
But I cant figure out how to do it.

Anyone?

edit:
MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,headsepline]{report}
\geometry{left=2cm, right=2cm, top=2.5cm, bottom=2cm}
\linespread {1.25}\selectfont
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}
\frenchspacing
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{geometry}

\begin{document}

    %...
    % need table here
    % ...

\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Now you have enough reputation for voting answers :) BTW: welcome to TeX.SX!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{ragged2e,array}
\newcommand\MC[1]{\multicolumn{2}{|c}{%
  \tabular{@{\quad} >{\Centering}p{\dimexpr2.5cm} @{\quad}}
    CPU targets,\\byte offset #1\endtabular}}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{*4{| p{1.25cm} | >{\RaggedLeft}p{1.25cm} }| }
31 & 24 & 23 & 16 & 15 & 8 & 7 & 0\\\hline
\MC3 & \MC2 & \MC1 & \MC0 \vrule\\\hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: awesome code, thanks! Cant vote up your answer, have too low reputation, sorry, can only select as accepted answer

Answer (score 6):

With [`bytefield`](http://ctan.org/pkg/bytefield) help you can easily get

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{bytefield}

\begin{document}
\begin{bytefield}[bitheight=8ex,endianness=big]{32}
    \bitheader{31,24,23,16,15,8,7,0}\\
    \bitbox{8}{CPU targets,\\ byte offset 3}
    \bitbox{8}{CPU targets,\\ byte offset 2}
    \bitbox{8}{CPU targets,\\ byte offset 1}
    \bitbox{8}{CPU targets,\\ byte offset 0}
\end{bytefield}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: this is also a very helpful answer, thanks! I would vote your answer up, but I cant, for having too low reputation, sorry

Answer (score 3):

Here's an implementation with low level commands:

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\bitstable}[5][\columnwidth]{%
  $\m@th\vcenter{\vbox{\bits@table{#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}{#5}}}$%
}

\newcommand\bits@table[5]{%
  \offinterlineskip
  \@tempdima=#1\relax
  \advance\@tempdima-4\p@
  \@tempdima=.25\@tempdima
  \tabskip=\z@
  \halign{%
    \vrule##\hfil&
    ##&
    \hfil\vrule##\hfil&
    ##&
    \hfil\vrule##\hfil&
    ##&
    \hfil\vrule##\hfil&
    ##&
    \hfil\vrule##\cr
    &
    \footnotesize\rlap{\,31}\hfil\vrule\hfil\llap{24\,}&
    &
    \footnotesize\strut\rlap{\,23}\hfil\vrule\hfil\llap{16\,}&
    &
    \footnotesize\strut\rlap{\,15}\hfil\vrule\hfil\llap{8\,}&
    &
    \footnotesize\strut\rlap{\,7}\hfil\vrule\hfil\llap{0\,}&
    \cr
    height 1pt&\hfil\vrule\hfil&&\hfil\vrule\hfil&&\hfil\vrule\hfil&&\hfil\vrule\hfil&\cr
    \noalign{\hrule height 0.8pt}
    width0.8pt height 3pt&&
    width0.8pt&&
    width0.8pt&&
    width0.8pt&&
    width0.8pt\cr
    width0.8pt&
    \bits@tablebox{#2}&
    width0.8pt&
    \bits@tablebox{#3}&
    width0.8pt&
    \bits@tablebox{#4}&
    width0.8pt&
    \bits@tablebox{#5}&
    width0.8pt\cr
    width0.8pt height 3pt&&
    width0.8pt&&
    width0.8pt&&
    width0.8pt&&
    width0.8pt\cr
    \noalign{\hrule height 0.8pt}
  }%
}
\newcommand{\bits@tablebox}[1]{%
  \parbox{\@tempdima}{\centering\strut#1\strut}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\noindent
\bitstable
  {CPU targets\\ byte offset $3$}
  {CPU targets\\ byte offset $2$}
  {CPU targets\\ byte offset $1$}
  {CPU targets\\ byte offset $0$}

\bigskip

\noindent
\bitstable[.8\linewidth]
  {CPU targets\\ byte offset $3$}
  {CPU targets\\ byte offset $2$}
  {CPU targets\\ byte offset $1$}
  {CPU targets\\ byte offset $0$}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here, I introduce `\boxit` to make each individual box.  It takes 3 arguments (the text, the upper bit, and the lower bit).  It also has an optional argument of the box width, default 0.2\textwidth, so that 4 boxes take up 0.8\textwidth.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[usestackEOL]{stackengine}
\def\mystrut{\rule[-2pt]{\fboxrule}{2ex}}
\newcommand\boxit[4][.2\textwidth]{%
  \leavevmode\unskip%
  {\small\sffamily%
  \fboxsep=0pt%
  \def\stacktype{L}%
  \strutlongstacks{T}%
  \def\stackalignment{r}%
  \stackon{\def\stackalignment{l}%
  \stackon{\def\stackalignment{c}%
  \stackon{\fbox{\addstackgap[1pt]{\makebox[#1]{\Longunderstack{#2}}}}}{\mystrut}%
  }{\mystrut\,#3}%
  }{#4\,\mystrut}}%
  \kern-.5\fboxrule\ignorespaces%
}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{center}
\boxit{CPU targets,\\byte offset 3}{31}{24}
\boxit{CPU targets,\\byte offset 2}{23}{16}
\boxit{CPU targets,\\byte offset 1}{15}{8}
\boxit{CPU targets,\\byte offset 0}{7}{0}
\end{center}
\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

[image]